# What is correct fstab line for root file system in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab

I have accidentally `fstab` on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and now it loads in read-only mode.

After the accident there was line:

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/556d8ecf-44cd-402b-8fd0-d120ccd61491 /mnt/556d8ecf-44cd-402b-8fd0-d120ccd61491 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

I changed it to

`/dev/sda1 / auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

and it fixed the read-only problem, but now I cannot run `sudo`

What is the proper line for root mount in `fstab`?

Comment: Was it mounted read only because it had errors? In that case you should have run `fsck` on it.

Comment: take out the nosuid from that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Ubuntu the default line generally looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=eafe03c8-55fd-4f2c-b1eb-ed8e174f55e9 /     ext4    errors=remount-ro    0       1
```

The file system UUID will be specfic to your system. Get it with `sudo lsblk -o "NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,UUID"`

ext4 is usually the default but it will say in the FSTYPE column of lsblk.